# Solving the matrix quadratic equation: A.X.X + B.X + C == 0 analytically

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to solve a matrix quadratic of the form, $AXX + BX = -C$ analytically for $X$. Where $A$, $X$, $B$, and $C$ are $N \times N$ matrices.

I tried using `Solve`, but got a message saying the system cannot be solved with methods available to `Solvep`. Is there any other way?

## Edit

If no analytical solution exists, it is possible to derive conditions on when the numerical solution exists?

Comment: Are you trying to solve it symbolically or do your matrices have values in them? Please show your matrices if you can.

Comment: The matrices are symbolic. Will update.

Comment: Have a look at  [discrete-time algebraic Riccati equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145225/how-to-solve-this-quadratic-matrix-equation)  and specifically `DiscreteRiccatiSolve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
n = 3;
X = Array[x, {n, n}];
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
f = (a.X + b).X + c;
sol = FindRoot[Thread[Flatten[f] == 0], Table[{Flatten[X][[i]], 0 }, {i, 1, n n}]]
f /. sol
```

Depending on the generated matrices, the result could be wordless. Some systems may not have real solutions.

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned in comments that their matrices are symbolic.

Comment: I assumed that for systems with dimensions $\ge 3 \times 3$ is practically impossible to tackle symbolically this problem.

Comment: My system is 3x3 =)

Comment: @hipHopMetropolisHastings yeah so Cesareo is right. A symbolic solution would be practically impossible. Would Cesareo's solution work for you? Otherwise, please specify your problem better